# передача параметра в контроллер c помощью AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Необходимо при клике на ссылку передать параметр на контроллер по методу Get. Параметр должен браться с этой ссылки(путь папки).FileInfo.Name ="C:\" Кусок кода:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="myapp">

<head>
  <title>File System</title>
  <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="FileInfoesController">
  <ul ng-repeat="FileInfo in li">
    <li>
      <a href="" ng-click="someMethod()">               {{FileInfo.Name}}</a> 
    </li>
  </ul>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var myapp = angular.module("myapp", [])
     myapp.controller("FileInfoesController", function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get("http://localhost:58303/api/FileInfoes").success(function(response) {
        $scope.li = response;
      });
    });

     //Test code
  </script>
```

---

```
public class FileInfoModel
{
    public List<FileInfo> findAll()
    {
        List<FileInfo> li =new List<FileInfo>();
        DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
        foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
        {
            if (d.DriveType == DriveType.Fixed)
            {
                li.Add(new FileInfo { Name = d.Name});
            }
        }
        return li;
    }



    var myapp = angular.module("myapp", [])
    myapp.controller("FileInfoesController", function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("http://localhost:58303/api/FileInfoes").success(function (response) {
            $scope.li = response;
        });
    });
    $scope.someMethod = functin(path){
        $http.get("http://localhost:58303/api/FileInfoes/findAll?id="+path).success(function (response) {
            $scope.li = response;
        });
    };
```

Comment: что за _кусок кода_ в вопросе, и как он относится к вопросу?

Comment: Есть ссылка на контроллер.  {{FileInfo.Name}} = D:/ . При клике на нее мне необходимо передать ее строчное значение в контроллер. Как это сделать в моем случае? В браузере у меня сейчас так: C:\
D:\

Comment: что значит _ссылка на контроллер_? что значит _передать ее строчное значение в контроллер_? _Как это сделать в моем случае?_ - какой у тебя случай?

Comment: Вот почти весь код. Я нахожу все диски и вывожу их списком. А теперь при выборе диска я должен отправить его на контроллер FileInfoesController : ApiController  public List<FileInfo> findAll(string id) { /*МОЙ КОД*/}.

Comment: что именно не получается? у тебя есть базовый адрес, у тебя есть _FileInfo.Name_ - значение параметра? не понятно как в урл параметр добавить?

Comment: Да. Надо этот же параметр передать на тот же контроллер, на метод который принимает параметр

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Большая часть кода уже написана, нахватает только передачи параметра в функцию

```
ng-click="someMethod(FileInfo.Name)">
```

И уже в самой функции отправлять нужный запрос, конкретный url зависит от настроек роутинга

```
$scope.someMethod = functin(path){
     $http.get("http://localhost:58303/api/FileInfoes/findAll?id="+path);
}
```

Comment: Сделал так,только теперь при загрузке все ломается. На экране {{FileInfo.Name}}. У меня в скрипте проблемы с синтаксимом как я понимаю, но не могу понять где

Comment: @АнтонЕвсеев, код в комментариях нечитаем, это раз, непонятно что ты хотел сказать этим кодом, это два

Comment: <blink><script type="text/javascript">
           var myapp = angular.module("myapp", [])
           myapp.controller("FileInfoesController", function ($scope, $http) {
            $http.get("http://localhost:58303/api/FileInfoes").success(function (response) {
                $scope.li = response;
            });
        });
        $scope.someMethod = functin(path){
            $http.get("http://localhost:58303/api/FileInfoes/findAll?id="+path).success(function (response) {
                $scope.li = response;
            });
        };
          
     </script></blink>

Comment: @АнтонЕвсеев, я повторюсь: _код в комментариях нечитаем, это раз, непонятно что ты хотел сказать этим кодом, это два_. Кроме того html в комментариях вообще не поддреживается

Comment: добавил скрипт в свой вопрос. Что подправить,чтоб работало?

Comment: @АнтонЕвсеев, во-первых, надо смотреть на ошибки в консоли, во-вторых, код должен быть _внутри_ ангуляровского контроллера, а не где-то сбоку

Comment: Ошибку нашел в синтаксисе у себя. А как правильно его в контроллер поместить?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43986/discussion-between-grundy-and--).

Comment: Спасибо!Разобрался, работает! =)